# mongoDB Geospatial Query $geoWithin got error 'Loop is not closed'

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial

i am newbie for Geospatial Query of mongodb and i try search for point within polygon which have code like below :

```
db.properties.find({
  location:{
    $geoWithin : {
      $geometry : {
        type:"Polygon",
        coordinates: [[
            [104.9172382, 11.57934524],
            [104.9146632, 11.5724502],
            [104.92753788, 11.57976566]
        ]]
        } 
      } 
    }
  })
```

and my data table look like below :
[image]

i want to get result of all point is inside polygon.but i really have no clue

this error alway popup

> |____/ Mongo Server error (MongoQueryException): Query failed with
>   error code 2 and error message 'Loop is not closed: [ [ 104.9172382,
>   11.57934524 ], [ 104.9146632, 11.5724502 ], [ 104.92753788, 11.57976566 ] ]' on server

thank for any idea !

Answer (score 10):

i found answer that we need to start coordinate and close coordinates are the same value.

```
db.properties.find({
  location:{
    $geoWithin : {
      $geometry : {
        type:"Polygon",
        coordinates:[
            [
                [ 104.9212999921292 , 11.575955591122819 ] , // start loop
                [ 104.92129194550216 , 11.575198826419006 ] ,
                [ 104.92298978380859 , 11.575238241297862 ] ,
                [ 104.92291736416519 , 11.576023910057827 ] ,
                [ 104.9212999921292 , 11.575955591122819 ] // close loop
            ]   
        ]
       }
     } 
   }
})
```

Comment: I already have my dara imported. How can I *'close the loop'*? ie. how can I update the docs to have the first element as the last one too?

Comment: no can't do, i didn't see info for that in mongo.https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/

Comment: This finally solved it for me! It was just a matter of the last coordinate being the same as the initial. Cheers man!